# standard text and image size in android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

Hi
I am reading XML from web and displaying them in a listview. The xml contain an image location so I am displaying the image as well along with text. 
The image size is 48*48 px as suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_list.html). But when I see the list view in actual device, the image looks very small. Any idea about how to make that image a little bit big?? is there any standard image and text size??
This is my layout:-

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/name"
  android:textSize="16sp" 
  android:textStyle="bold" 
  android:textColor="#2B2B2B" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
```

/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dip instead of px. when you use dip, it appears more adjustable and good on different screens.

Comment: I am not using px anywhere. am I? The actual image size is 48*48 px. Did u mean to create the image 48*48 dp?

Comment: if you set android:layout_width="32dip"
    android:layout_height="32dip" it will work. if the image seems still compact, you can increases the dip which I stated here

Comment: Thanks dude. This is something I was looking for. works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice on Android to declare layout size by pixels. This page is straight from Google on the subject: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  I would do something like this

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

and see how that looks. Don't forget to test on multiple screen sizes before you finish. You can do that by creating different AVDs for the emulator.

You can use pixels if you really want to, but remember that its going to look different on different devices.

```
android:layout_height="96dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Comment: using android:layout_height="96dip" gives me a good result at this moment. But still I am going to test it in different devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ImageView like this:

Modify the width and height values to your liking, but use the dip measurement. With the scaleType property you can tell the framework to stretch your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

to your ImageView XML. This will not scale your image, but center it in your view.